# Phone number regex - Merge three conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regex function which will validate a phone number field based on certain conditions and show alerts for each of the three cases.

Practically I have this 3 regex functions which I want to combine in a single one.

```
/^3\d{9}$/; //If it starts with 3 and has another 9 numbers it's a cellphone

/^0\d{7,10}$/; //If it starts with 0 and has another 7-10 numbers it's a landline

/^(?:00|\+)/; //If it starts with 00 or a + sign, it's an international number
```

What I am trying to achieve, is to have a javascript function which will combine this three regex functions and show a certain message in case the number is not valid.

So for example if the number starts with 3 but it has less or more than 9 numbers after the 3, probably it's a wrong cellphone number so I want to warn the user about that. Same thing for the Landline. For the international numbers I simply want to make them aware that it might be an international number because it starts with double 00 or + sign.

My problem is that I don't know how to combine this three regex values in a single one, which will allow me to build a simple and clean javascript code.

Comment: Great question! I'm curious to see what the answer is.

Comment: You can combine all 3 by putting `|` between them, but I think the "fuzzy logic" you're describing would need to be more sophisticated than that.

Comment: If it fails all 3 (when you combine them) you can then see which one did fail. I like your spirit here, but it might be better to check them individually so you can give an adequate response.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need a single regex at all, but multiple conditions that do different things etc.

Comment: Brian Kernihan wrote "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." - in other words, go with the version which is more accessible as opposed to more elegant!

Comment: If you need different warning messages, use different/separate regexps.

Comment: What about something like `001234567`, is it a landline or international, it could match both conditions in this case? I think you need narrower checks ?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm This is why I asked. Not only to find a solution of how to put them together but also to understand if it's a good idea or not.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Yimin Rong I understand. I was trying to consider all aspects and find the solution which combines both accessibility and elegance. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @adeneo Yes it can match in rare cases. But I am doing this simply to warn the users that it might be an international number. No action will be taken when a number has been validated. The suggestion/warning might be wrong in the rare cases when the international number is short (including the 4 initial country codes like 0039) but this are probably very rare cases because no phone number which includes the country code is so short usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you: `/^(?:3\d{9}|0\d{7,10}|(?:00|\+)\d+)$/g`

```js
const testPhoneNumber = number => /^(?:3\d{9}|0\d{7,10}|(?:00|\+)\d+)$/.test(number)

const numbers = [123, "+48667065144", 3111222333, "001234567", "00123456879", 6473812354, 3475456389, 7483925821]

for (const number of numbers) {
  console.log(`${number} is ${testPhoneNumber(number) ? "valid": "not valid"} phone number`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match(/(^3\d{9}$)|(^0\d{7,10}$)|(^(?:00|\+))/)
```

this will capture the matched data in an array (size 4).

position 0 : the matched data

position 1 : matched data of the 1st regexp

....

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check(number) {
 //var number = '3123456789';
 //var number = '01234567';
 //var number = '001';

 var regexList = [
  '^3\\d{9}$', //If it starts with 3 and has another 9 numbers it's a cellphone
  '^0\\d{7,10}$', //If it starts with 0 and has another 7-10 numbers it's a landline
  '^[0]{2}|[\+]' //If it starts with 00 or a + sign, it's an international number
 ];

 for (var r in regexList)
  if (number.match(new RegExp(regexList[r])))
   break;
  else
   r = null;
   
 switch (r) {
  case "0":
   alert('If it starts with 3 and has another 9 numbers it\'s a cellphone');
   break;
  case "1":
   alert('If it starts with 0 and has another 7-10 numbers it\'s a landline');
   break;
  case "2":
   alert('If it starts with 00 or a + sign, it\'s an international number');
   break;
  default:
   alert('Invalid number');
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numberToCheck" />
<input type="button" onclick="check(document.getElementById('numberToCheck').value)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As "elegant" as I can make it...

```
var input = '00372553253';
var matches = [];

// The following is technically one line!
[
    {regex: /^3\d{9}$/, type: "cellphone"},
    {regex: /^0\d{7,10}$/, type: "landline"},
    {regex: /^(?:00|\+)/, type: "international"}
].forEach(
    function(element) {
        if (element.regex.test(input))
            matches.push(element.type);
    }
);

alert(matches);
```

The test case will actually match two regexes!